# A Recursion method that returns number of digits, help for 0

Tags: java, recursion

So I'm doing this exercise and my teacher says that he wants the num/10 in this line:`System.out.print(numDigits(num/10));` in the method (so that if the original number is 0 then it will return 1 digit rather than 0), but I have no idea where he wants it.

(*must be done with recursion to count the number of digits of a number)

To me this way is simple, but I guess if you're writing a lot of code you don't want to keep typing x/10.

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumDigits
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    int num;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    num = input.nextInt();
    input.close();

    System.out.print(numDigits(num/10));
  }

  public static int numDigits(int x)
  {  
    if (x == 0)
    {return 1;}
    else
    {
      return 1 + numDigits(x/10);
    }
  }
}
```

I guess I could do this, but it takes more code... : /

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumDigits
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    int num;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    num = input.nextInt();
    input.close();

    System.out.print(numDigits(num, num));
  }

  public static int numDigits(int x, int num)
  {  
    if (num == 0)
    {return 1;}
    else if (x == 0)
    {return 0;}
    else
    {
      return 1 + numDigits(x/10, num);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: A nice code for unit testing, some test for 0, 1, 15, 20, 100, etc might help you design a good algorithm. Hint `Math.log` might provide a clever way ;)

Comment: I told my teacher that calling the method with num/10 instead of putting more code into the method was simpler (so that 0 won't have 0 digits), but he says "you're right there, jut don't have the num/10 in the main method, but instead in the recursive method"

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that numDigits returns the number of decimal digits in a number

Here is a straightforward solution:

```
public static int numDigits(int x) {
    return Integer.toString(x).length();
}
```

Worried about locales/radix/speed/negatives? Try this one:

```
public static int numDigits(int x) {
    if (x == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return (int) (Math.log10(Math.abs(x))) + 1;
    }
}
```

However, if recursion is required:

```
public static int numDigits(int x) {
    if (x > -10 && x < 10) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return numDigits(x / 10) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god I have to admit that your answer sir..is great.So simple and elegant

Answer (score 1):

Well, that first division is removed rather easily.

```
public class NumDigits
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    int num;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    num = input.nextInt();
    input.close();

    System.out.print(numDigits(num));
  }
```

And now your check for 0 still works in the numDigits function, and even more it does for the first '0' as well. Only thing you need to tweak now is the recursive call itself, left as an exercise, as it is still homework.

Comment: I know, that's the question. I don't know what to do with the numDigits method

Comment: Start with the basic answer: take the absoulte value of your number if negatives are allowed. Then, if it is smaller then 10 you know the answer right? If it is larger then 10, e.g. 123, you can do your `/10` trick.

Answer (score 1):

Using a recursion method you can achieve SuperDigit By this way

```
public class SuperDigit
{
 //static int sum = 0;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
int n = 8596854;



System.out.println(sum(n));
}
static int sum (int num)
{
if (num != 0)
{
    return (num % 10 + sum (num / 10));
}
else
{
   return 0;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just do this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumDigits
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
int num;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
num = input.nextInt();
input.close();

System.out.print(numDigits(num));
}

public static int numDigits(int num)
{  
if ((num/10) == 0)
{return 1;}
else
{
  return 1 + numDigits(num/10);
}
}
}
```

this way the "num/10" is in the recursive method not the main method, and the zero problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

well Im an idiot. the answer is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumDigits
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    long num;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    num = input.nextInt();
    input.close();

    System.out.print(numDigits(num));
  }

  public static long numDigits(long x)
  {  
    if (x/10 == 0)
    {return 1;}
    else
    {
      return 1 + numDigits(x/10);
    }
  }
}
```

I assumed that it wouldn't work so I didn't try it